# How to add a partial border to header title CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

Is it possible to use a border like this in CSS?

[CSS Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeBif.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

There's possibly a smarter way with pseudo-classes. But here's a simple solution that uses a few positioned divs for each "border".

```css
.container { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 2;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.box.border {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;      
}

.box.left {
  background: yellow;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}

.box.right {
  background: blue;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='box'></div>
 <div class='box border left'></div>
 <div class='box border right'></div>
</div>
```